# Percentage higher than a value

Tags: percentages

I am doing an experiment where I get two values in two cases. Let's say the values are 10 in case 1 and 15 in case 2. For case 2, I want to report how high it is compared to case 1 in terms of percentage.

If I calculate `(15-10) / 10 = 0.5`, so can I say the result for case 2 is 50% higher compared to case 1 ?

If the score for case 2 was lower, e.g. 5, then if I calculate `(10 - 5)/10 = 0.5`, o can I say the result for case 2 is 50% lower compared to case 1 ?

Comment: Yes you can say that. Also,$\frac{15}{10} = \frac{3}{2} = 1+\frac{1}{2}$ which is half or $50 \%$ more than the first case.

Comment: Be careful, though, because while the results in case 2 are $50$% larger than those in case 1, the results in case 1 are  $33.33$% smaller than those in case 2... (when case 1 is 10 and case 2 is 15)